# Why does 人 have a different tone when it's part of the word 大人?

Tags: tones

The pinyin for 人 is rén but when it's part of 大人, it's written as dà ren. This is the only word with 人 where that happens (at least in the list of words I went through). Why is there a change in tone?

Comment: It is known as [Neutral tone](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Neutral_tone)

Answer (score 1):

> Google Translate: 人 / rén/ ; 大人 /dàrén/. I don't see the different pinyin for 人

~

> CantoDict :
>
> 人/ren2/
>
> [大人](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/6/) /da4 ren5/2/
>
> (1) adult; grown-up
>
> (2) Your Honour; Your Excellency
>
> (3) [literary] Dear (Father/Mother)
>
> (4) great man; person of high rank or noble mind
>
> Note:
>
> *1: Pinyin da4 ren5 is used for first two meanings; da4 ren2 for latter two.*
>
> *2: "Your Honour" is mainly used on a judge.*

In Mandarin:

- 人 on its own is pronounced as /rén/
- When 大人 meant "adult" or "your Honour" 人 is pronounced as /ren/.
- When 大人 meant "Dear" or "great man" 人 pronounced as /rén/

So, you only need to remember 人 pronounces differently as /ren/ only when you mean to say 大人(adult) or 大人 (your Honour). In all other instances 人 is pronounced as /rén/